# Mutating Table error in row level trigger

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

Write a database trigger to

1. Halt the transaction between the the time 6pm to 10am on table
2. Give the appropriate message if the record exceed more than 10
3. Delete data older than 2 months from Mon - Sat and date shouldn't be 1st of the month. 
   (i.e. leave Sunday & 1st OF THE MONTH DATA older THAN 2 months)

I tried this code,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMP_INFO_BFT BEFORE
  INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON EMP_INFO
  FOR EACH ROW 
  DECLARE l_TIME NUMBER(10);
  l_RECORD NUMBER;
  BEGIN
   l_TIME:=TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24');
    IF l_TIME NOT BETWEEN 18 AND 10 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003,'TIME ALREADY OVER.....TRANSACTION NOT ALLOWED NOW');
   END IF;
    DELETE
    FROM EMP_INFO
    WHERE TRUNC (HIRE_DATE )                < ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE), -2)
    AND TO_CHAR (TRUNC (HIRE_DATE ), 'DY') != 'SUN'
    AND TO_CHAR (TRUNC (HIRE_DATE ), 'DD') != '01';
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_RECORD FROM EMP_INFO;
    IF l_RECORD>=10 THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20005,'10 RECORD ALLOWED IN EMP_INFO TABLE');
    END IF;
  END;
```

I got mutating error while inserting.

Answer (score 0):

**Mutating error**

[Check this link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_avoiding_mutating_table_error.htm) which basically says:

"If a trigger does result in a mutating table error, the only real option is to rewrite the trigger as a statement-level trigger.

Mutating table errors only impact row level triggers."

Your code doesn't reference `:NEW` or `:OLD`, so changing it to a statement level trigger should be easy, just remove the `FOR EACH ROW`.

**PS**

I don't think your BETWEEN will work.

Changing

```
IF l_TIME NOT BETWEEN 18 AND 10 THEN
```

to

```
IF l_TIME BETWEEN 10 AND 18 THEN
    NULL;
ELSE
```

would fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Make this trigger as autonomous trigger, check the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMP_INFO_BFT BEFORE
  INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON EMP_INFO
  FOR EACH ROW 
  DECLARE l_TIME NUMBER(10);
  l_RECORD NUMBER;
pragma autonomous_transaction;
  BEGIN
   l_TIME:=TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24');
    IF l_TIME NOT BETWEEN 18 AND 10 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003,'TIME ALREADY OVER.....TRANSACTION NOT ALLOWED NOW');
   END IF;
    DELETE
    FROM EMP_INFO
    WHERE TRUNC (HIRE_DATE )                < ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE), -2)
    AND TO_CHAR (TRUNC (HIRE_DATE ), 'DY') != 'SUN'
    AND TO_CHAR (TRUNC (HIRE_DATE ), 'DD') != '01';
    commit;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_RECORD FROM EMP_INFO;
    IF l_RECORD>=10 THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20005,'10 RECORD ALLOWED IN EMP_INFO TABLE');
    END IF;
  END;
```